# PHP - How to echo the 'query result count' on the page before the 'query results' are shown/counted

Tags: php, wordpress

*How can I put the true 'Search Result Count' before the search results appear on the page?*

```
<div><?php echo $search_result_count.' RESULTS'; ?></div>

<div class="search-results">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('/include/pattern','listings'); ?>           
        <?php $search_result_count++ ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>

<div><?php echo __('THERE ARE '.$search_result_count.' RESULTS'); ?></div>
```

*Currently this displays as...*

```
0 RESULTS

 - LISTING #1
 - LISTING #2
 - LISTING #3
 - LISTING #4

THERE ARE 4 RESULTS
```

*What I want is this...*

```
4 RESULTS

 - LISTING #1
 - LISTING #2
 - LISTING #3
 - LISTING #4

THERE ARE 4 RESULTS
```

There must be a few ways to do it.. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you can't show the value of a variable before you you assign the value to it, which you currently are trying to do..

Comment: not possible but may be you can achieve it by using jquery or javascript.

Comment: Just do the loop twice. Once in top, only calculating `$search_result_count` and then again displaying the results. Unless you have like 10.000 posts in your list, it won't really be a performance issue.

Answer (score -1):

If u are using PHP and MySQL, then there is a far far easy solution- using [**mysqli_num_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Example code-

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: He's using Wordpress and wants to count a search result. Doing a manual query to the DB doesn't really help him.